# mprotect subset of functions in shared library

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, ld, linker-scripts

I'm trying to `mprotect` a subset of functions bundled in a shared library for the purposes of a larger level feature.

Given the requirements around page-alignment for `mprotect`, I've setup a separate section in my linker script that ensures that alignment:

```
SECTIONS
{
    .protectedsection ALIGN(4096) : {
        *(.protectedsection)
    }    
}

INSERT AFTER .rodata;
```

And in the declaration of the function I want protection on, I add the relevant GCC attributes:

```
// Setup with protection
void bar(int a) __attribute__ ((section ("protectedsection")));

// Setup without protection
void foo(int a);
```

I compile the resultant C code with GCC, along with the -T option to pass in the linker file:

```
gcc -fpic -shared -T linkerscript.ld libfuncs.c -o libfuncs.so
```

Objdump'ing it reveals that while it is in the right section, the alignment isn't right:

```
Disassembly of section protectedsection:

00000000000010da <_Z3bari>:
    10da:   55                      push   %rbp
    10db:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    10de:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
    10e2:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
    10e5:   48 8d 3d e1 00 00 00    lea    0xe1(%rip),%rdi        # 11cd <_fini+0x9>
    10ec:   e8 df f4 ff ff          callq  5d0 <puts@plt>
    10f1:   90                      nop
    10f2:   c9                      leaveq 
    10f3:   c3                      retq
```

Is what I'm trying to do here possible, and if so, how?

Comment: "the alignment isn't right" -- what is the *section* alignment? Please show `readelf -WS` output.

Comment: Given that I had requested protectedsection be aligned to 12 byte boundary (4096), the eventual address of the section (0x10da) didn't match that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem - changing 'INSERT AFTER .rodata' to 'INSERT AFTER .text' fixed my problem. With that, I was able to setup a 'buffered' region for the code I want to have mprotect'ed, and it all works like a charm!

Comment: Hello @cradical, I am glad you were able to solve your problem. However, reading this comment makes me wonder how did you "setup a `buffered region` for the code" to have `mprotect`'ed? I think this is very interesting, and I wanted to hear your insight on it.